# How can I store mouse moves in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, event-listener, mousemove

I've made a canvas and I need to track the positions that have been drawn. I created a 2d array the size of the canvas which i've initially set to false and want to set to true once a point has been painted. After painting and logging my array to the console its not showing any of the elements changed to true. Ultimately I want to draw on the canvas, turn drawn on points to boolean true value, click a button that takes the array and do something with it. Here's my code, apologies if i've made a mess of explaining this but i'm new to it all.

```
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const size = 500;
const scale = 1;
const resolution = size / scale;
ctx.scale(scale, scale);


function make2dArray() {
    let arr = new Array(resolution);
    for (let i = 0; i < resolution; i++) {
        arr[i] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < resolution; j++) {
            arr[i][j] = false;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}



let newArray = make2dArray();


  
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', draw);
document.addEventListener('mousedown', setPosition);
document.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);

let pos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
// new position from mouse event
function setPosition(e) {
    pos.x = e.clientX;
    pos.y = e.clientY;
}

// Resize canvas
function resize() {
    ctx.canvas.width = resolution;
    ctx.canvas.height = resolution;
}

function draw(e) {
  
    if (e.buttons !== 1) return;

    ctx.beginPath();

    ctx.lineWidth = 100;
    ctx.lineCap = 'round';
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';

    ctx.moveTo(pos.x, pos.y);
    setPosition(e);
    ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);

    ctx.stroke(); 

    //set newArray cells to true when they've been drawn on

    newArray[pos.x][pos.y] = true;
    
}
```

Comment: what updates pos.x and pos.y?

Comment: "facepalm". Sorry again! :/ I left that out when i copied the code across. setPosition() updates pos.x and pos.y....i think.

Comment: Consider creating an accessor `index2d = (x,y) => y * resolution + x` and using a single one-dimensional array `newArray[index2d(pos.x, pos.y)] = true`

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understood what you wanted - *Click and paint* ;)

You can find a couple of comments in the code comments:

```js
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  // get the actual playground size to calculate mouse position relative to canva
  let {width: canvas_width, height: canvas_height} = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();

  // position can also be a const object :)
  let pos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

  // maybe it's better to have all lost position for painting 
  // ... play around with it.
  let last_pos = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };
  
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const size = 1000;
  const scale = 1;
  const resolution = size / scale;
  ctx.scale(scale, scale);
  
  function make2dArray() {
    let arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < resolution; i++) {
      arr[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < resolution; j++) {
        arr[i][j] = false;
      }
    }
    return arr;
  }

  let newArray = make2dArray();
  
  function setPosition(e) {
    // calculate relative location for canvas and array
    pos.x = Math.round(e.clientX / canvas_width * resolution);
    pos.y = Math.round(e.clientY / canvas_height * resolution);
  }
  
  function resize() {
    // recalc on current resize
    ({width: canvas_width, height: canvas_height} = document.body.getBoundingClientRect());
    // not really useful on resize because resolution doesn't change 
    ctx.canvas.width = resolution;
    ctx.canvas.height = resolution;
  }

  function draw(e) {
    if (e.buttons !== 1) return;
    // down draw more als your client can ;)
    requestAnimationFrame(() => {

      // trivial fall back not to start at 0,0 ... you may find better solutions   
      if (last_pos.x > 0 && last_pos.y > 0) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.lineWidth = 100;
        ctx.lineCap = 'round';
        ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
        ctx.moveTo(last_pos.x, last_pos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(pos.x, pos.y);
        ctx.stroke();
      }
      
      ({x: last_pos.x, y: last_pos.y} = pos);
      
      // prevent array from out ouf range coordinates
      if (pos.x < resolution && pos.y < resolution) {
        newArray[pos.x][pos.y] = true;
      }
    })
  }

  resize();
  // may be not what you had in mind... play with it
  window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', setPosition);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', draw);
  // canvas.addEventListener('mouseenter', setPosition);
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
    canvas {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, Ye i should have included that code. Its part of a large block of code and i forgot to include the declaration for resolution. I just updated it there. When i log pos.x pos.y their values correspond to the mouse position. As in their value change dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Um, you can just `push`

```
function setPosition(e) {
    pos.x = e.clientX;
    pos.y = e.clientY;
    arr.push({y:pos.y, x:pos.x})
}
```

Comment: If I do that its just add's them positions to the end of my array creating an array bigger than the one that I created originally. What I really need to do is go into the array and change the value from 'false' to 'true' the points that are stored in pos.x and pos.y.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was where I was logging to the console. I'm still not 100% on it but I think its an async problem (still trying to get my head around that concept). The array was actually being filled up fine and when I created a method that accessed the array it was all there. Lesson for me was not to always rely on console.log. Thanks for all your input guys. No doubt i'll be back here again...soon